# How to find the running network services and the port and user

Tags: 12.04, networking, users, ps, netstat

I want to find a list of all network services running on my system, including details of the port and services and the users.
I know that I need to use netstat, ps and fuser. but I don't know how to write the command.
Do I need to write a shell script to find all of them? or I can use in a line of commands?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the command : `sudo lsof -i -n -P`

This command lists the **Application Name**, **PID**, **User**, **IP version**, **Device ID** and the **Node with Port Name**. It shows both **TCP** and **UDP**.

Variations :

- To format it in a nice, readable way; use :

  `sudo lsof -i -n -P | more`
- To view view only **TCP** connections :

  `sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP | more`
- To view view only **UDP** connections :

  `sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep UDP | more`

Comment: Thanks boddy, I don't have lsof command, it is a basic system and I have to use those 3 commands of ps, fuser and netstat together to find the users.

Comment: run the following command : `sudo apt-get install lsof` and install lsof.