# SSH connection through port 443 fails

Tags: 16.04, networking, ssh

I'm working through [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-route-web-traffic-securely-without-a-vpn-using-a-socks-tunnel) and [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ssh-keys-with-putty-on-digitalocean-droplets-windows-users) tutorials from DigitalOcean and trying to set up an ssh connection on port 443 as per step 5. I've been able to get it working on port 22 (steps 1-4). I've checked the firewall and port 443 is open. I've changed the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file to:

```
 # What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
 Port 22
 Port 443
```

I've restarted the service:

```
sudo service ssh restart
sudo service sshd restart
```

When I login with putty on port 443 I get [a blank screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrXFZ.png). It works on port 22. Anything else I can do to get this working on port 443?

Edit:

```
  $ sudo lsof -i -n -P +c 0 | grep ':80\|:443'

  COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
  nginx   26964     root    6u  IPv4 2603510992      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
  nginx   26964     root    7u  IPv6 2603510993      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
  nginx   26964     root    8u  IPv4 2603510994      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
  nginx   26965 www-data    6u  IPv4 2603510992      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
  nginx   26965 www-data    7u  IPv6 2603510993      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
  nginx   26965 www-data    8u  IPv4 2603510994      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
```

Edit:

```
  $ sudo systemctl status sshd

  ● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-09-07 16:04:13 EDT; 1min 19s ago
   Main PID: 22845 (sshd)
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             ├─22103 sshd: deploy [priv]
             ├─...
             └─22853 pager

  Sep 07 16:04:13 server sshd[22845]: error: Bind to port 443 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Address already in use.
  Sep 07 16:04:13 server sshd[22845]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
```

Comment: Maybe the web server (Apache or Nginx) listen to this port, because this is the default HTTPS (SSL/TLS) port. Btw, the image doesn't provide any information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the running network services and the port and user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/573631/how-to-find-the-running-network-services-and-the-port-and-user)

Comment: I've added some more info above

Comment: The last line: `nginx   26965 www-data    8u  IPv4 2603510994      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)`. Wasn't there an error message after `sudo service sshd restart`?

Comment: Don't know how you knew that but I remembered that I usually use systemctl to manage the system. Please see edit above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the mentioned manual more carefully. Under step 5 is written:

> **If your connection is working, you are good to go and can stop
>   reading.** ...
>
> Ports that are often open include 80 (general web traffic) and 443
>   (SSL web traffic).
>
> If your <del>SSH</del> server isn't serving web content, we can tell
>   SSH to use one of these web ports to communicate over instead of the
>   default port 22. 443 is the best choice ...

In your case the output of the command `sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep www-data` is:

```
nginx   26965 www-data    6u  IPv4 2603510992      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx   26965 www-data    7u  IPv6 2603510993      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx   26965 www-data    8u  IPv4 2603510994      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
```

That means Nginx web server is serving web content and it uses port `80` and port `443`.

Also the output of `sudo systemctl status sshd` reports the following error:

```
error: Bind to port 443 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Address already in use.
```

**Everything is okay, just the web server Nginx listen on `Port 443`. If you want to use SSH connection on this port you should disable or reconfigure the web server.**

---

One port could be used as server's port only from one service. Two services can communicate through common port and within this relationship one of the services plays role as server and the another plays role as client.

---

If you want to use different SSH port, choice something above 10 000, usually it takes a long time to scan large range of ports, so hacker's bots usually scans the range 1-1000, or some specific ports as 22, 25, 80, 443. Don't forgot to open this port into the firewall, and if your connection is working on the new port, you can disable the default - 22.

---

References:

- [How to find the running network services and the port and user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/573631/how-to-find-the-running-network-services-and-the-port-and-user)

Comment: Thanks, I missed the line about the server . Because I am a beginner, 2 services cannot share a port?

Comment: You are welcome, @user61629! I've added an additional comment to the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @user61629, I've updated the answer according to the question - 2 services cannot share a port? - that I've missed.